# Breakpoints in knitR/RStudio

Tags: r, knitr, rstudio

Is there (or will there be) any way of setting breakpoints in an Rnw file? I want to do this when just running the code - I wouldn't expect to be able to do it when compiling PDF.

I can use browser(), but this automatically pops up a .active-rstudio-document window. Is there any way to stop it from doing this?

Comment: Perhaps re-poking the folks on the RStudio support forum (like you tried to do [back in July](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/202829206-Breakpoints-with-knitR)) is still the more likely place to get an answer for this product-specific question.

Comment: No, you can't do much better than browser() today. Debugging code in knitr documents in general is pretty tough, and something on our (admittedly long) laundry list of items to look at in 0.99.